# Simulating Integrals with Monte Carlo method

Tags: simulation, montecarlo

I´m trying to transform the integral:

[image]

I need to transform it to an integral that goes from 0 to 1 in order to apply the algorithm of Montecarlo I implemented. I´m comfortable applying the identities on single integrals, but I don´t really know how to apply the following identities to a double integral.

[image]

[image]

I investigated on books and found this hint, but I still don´t understand how to use it on a double  integral. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours, I was able to get the transformation. Hope it helps :)[image]